# how to check if a process is running in linux using python script

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to check the status of the `tcpdump` process on Linux inside a python script. (how to use `ps cax | grep tcpdump > /dev/null` in python or is there any other way?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [psutil](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) module

```
import psutil
process = 'tcpdump'
print([p.info for p in psutil.process_iter(attrs=['pid', 'name']) if process in p.info['name']])
```